# Append byte[] to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to read the `byte[]` for each file and adding it to MemoryStream. Below is the code which throws error. What I am missing in appending?

```
byte[] ba = null;
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
int startPosition = 0;
using (MemoryStream allFrameStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    foreach (string jpegFileName in fileNames)
    {
        ba = GetFileAsPDF(jpegFileName);

        allFrameStream.Write(ba, startPosition, ba.Length); //Error here
        startPosition = ba.Length - 1;
    }

    allFrameStream.Position = 0;

    ba = allFrameStream.GetBuffer();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", ba.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(ba);
    Response.End();
    Response.Close();              
}
```

Error:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection

Answer (score 8):

`startPosition` is not offset to MemoryStream, instead to `ba`. Change it as

```
allFrameStream.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
```

All byte arrays will be appended to `allFrameStream`

*BTW: Don't use `ba = allFrameStream.GetBuffer();` instead use `ba = allFrameStream.ToArray();`* (You actually don't want internal buffer of MemoryStream).

Comment: This is in a loop. Will it always overwrite the byte[]? since your offset is 0

Comment: @Billa It will **append** in every write, unless you change the Position  manually. That offset says *Write ba to memorystream from ba's offset 0 to len*

Comment: But when there are two images available, i get only last image in pdf document generated. First image is missing :(

Comment: @Billa Your code is now correct in the context of what you have asked. But appending byte arrays to a memorystream and expecting an image list is not a correct assumption. Out of scope of your question. Maybe you need `List<byte[]>` ?

Comment: Yes that could be the correct. Just push each byte[] in list and merge all bytes into memorystream.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation on [`Stream.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might help clarify the problem.

Streams are modelled as a continuous **sequence** of bytes. Reading or writing to a stream moves your position in the stream by the number of bytes read or written.

The second argument to `Write` is the index in the *source* array at which to start copying bytes from. In your case this is 0, since you want to read from the start of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a simple solution, not the best but is easy

```
 List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
 list.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
 list.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"));
 list.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("cccccccc"));

 byte[] c = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).